# Some WordPress permalink problems, probably depending by wrong .htaccess configuration?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I have import on my local webserver a backup of a website made using WordPress but I am finding some difficulties with **PermaLink** configuration

The main problem is that if I use the permalink setted as Article Name I can see the homepage but if I click on the articles links into the homepage (to see the article) I always obtain the following message error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL
>   /wordpress35/2012/10/11/se-milano-avesse-il-mare-anzi-no-la-montagna-di-campiglio/
>   was not found on this server.

If I instead I use the Default settings for permalink (`http://localhost/wordpress35/?p=123`) I have no problem and I can access to the articles in my website

I think that this is a **.htaccess** problem. Can you help me to create an **.htaccess** file that solve this problem?

My actual .htaccess file is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I need to use the URL format described as: `http://localhost/wordpress35/my-article-name`

Comment: Your WordPress .htaccess file from the live server should work as long as the rewrites on your local setup are enabled.

Comment: mmm what do you exactly mean? I have no .htaccess file in my WP installation folder, so I think that I have to create it, or am I mising something?

Comment: You need to have the .htaccess file, certainly. Do you not have one on the live server the site came from? ftp that one into place...or use the file example here to create one: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating a the wordpress .htaccess for your needs?

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

This should work if you didn't specify any change in the website's URL.
(If the homepage is still `http://localhost/wordpress35/`  )

Comment: mmm I have put this content into a new .htaccess file but still not work. ModRewrite module is activate on my Apache2 server. What could be? Some idea?

Comment: Try resetting your Apache server. 
If that does not work you might want go to your httpd and set 
`AllowOverride all`